# Famo.us - Is a Gridlayout always a Gridlayout?

Tags: grid-layout, famo.us

I am trying to ‘look’ at my screen in a grid format so I can lay out content based on that grid.

This isn’t strictly a gridlayout like having loads of photos or items evenly split across a screen, but understanding more the sizes and locations I can add surfaces or views.

[Grid layout http://www.pandafinity.com/Screen-Grid.jpg](http://www.pandafinity.com/Screen-Grid.jpg)

The above image is how I want to view the screen – so I can layout various items, some will span the smaller grid cells, some will be smaller (inside the grid cell), and some will span over multiple grid cells.

How would I create this approach using Famo.us?  Can I use the Gridlayout for this or is it best to get the screen dimensions and do some maths to look at alignment and origins?

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to use https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-flex.

Next bit is taken from the Github page (Hope Hein doesn't mind) :)

"
Flexible, animated and plugable layout-controller for famo.us, which:

- Smoothly animates renderables between layouts (using physics)
- Makes it easy to layout renderables (without having to create lots of modifiers)
- Is shipped with various commonly used layouts
- Allows you to easily create custom layouts and layout-helpers
- Is very good at creating responsive designs
  "

I think its a great approach and helps you split the layout from the renderables.

Answer (score 0):

J. Andrew Brassington made such a thing in Famo.us already, similar to Isotope or Masonry if you about know those. He might be one to contact: https://github.com/jabbrass

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.  I am actually looking into 'famous-flex (https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-flex) which looks pretty amazing.

Comment: Mmm, yeah, that's tasty. It doesn't do the thing masonry does when boxes are different sizes like J Andrew's, but definitely nice and more option-full. Let me see if I can get a link to J Andrew's.